# Reload class using custom class loader

Tags: java

i am planning for the hot deployment of class using the custom class loader.For this task i have written custom class loader. Which looks like

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
        public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(parent);
        }
        public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            if(!"classLoader.TestCase".equals(name))
                    return super.loadClass(name);
            try {
                String url = null;
                String clzName = null;
                url = "file:/home/naveen/workspace/JavaConcept/bin/classLoader/TestCase.class";
                    clzName = "classLoader.TestCase";
                }
                URL myUrl = new URL(url);
                URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int data = input.read();
             while(data != -1){
                    buffer.write(data);
                    data = input.read();
                }
                input.close();
                byte[] classData = buffer.toByteArray();
           return defineClass(clzName,classData, 0, classData.length);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
        }
}
```

Now i have a another class called TestCase which has an method called print().

```
public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
```

and i am calling it from main method something like this

```
public static void main(String arg[]) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

        TestCase t = new TestCase();
        t.print();

        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = CustomClassLoader.class.getClassLoader(); 
            classLoader = new CustomClassLoader(classLoader);
            Class clz = classLoader.loadClass("classLoader.TestCase");
            TestCase t2 = new TestCase();
            t2.print();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now here i want to do one thing that inside a main t.print() method is called which print hello and bye on console. Now i have a another version of this Testcase class's print method which only print Hello. So what i did i stated the program in debug mode and let the program going on untill the classLoader.loadClass() line. then i replaced the Testcase.class from directory structure with new version which print only hello.But still it showing the output Hello and Bye. 
Can someone help me what's wrong with this program or my understand regarding the class loader is not correct. Please correct me and help to complete my task.

Comment: Just wondering... Why do you need to deploy only this one class, rather than deploy a new build of the class library / application its part of?

Answer (score 0):

Custom class loaders are difficult to implement because of the many rules you need to keep in mind. In your case, I guess the problem is that your class file is part of your program, which means that if you try to load a class, the default class loader will load it before calling your loadClass() method that will never be called. Try removing your class file from your classpath so that its not part of your program, then your loadClass() should be called.

Second problem is that you are creating your TestCase object using new, that will invoke the default class loader, a better approach would be to call classLoader.loadClass() and then create an instance from the class returned, but if you cast to TestCase that it means that the class is defined in your default classloader which leads to the first problem. An alternative is to create an interface and cast to that interface in order to call your method.